# Why does this not give the 2nd last element of the array?

Tags: perl

```
print $some_array[$#some_array - 1];
```

My intuitive understanding is the above code should print the 2nd last element in @some_array.

However in reality it does not. It prints something I cannot made sense of.

Comment: What does it print? It works for me: `perl -e "@a = (1,2,3,4,5,6); print $a[$#a - 1];"` prints `5`

Comment: you're wrong about something. what does it print?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you include the line where you set `@some_array`, please?  Does the "something you cannot make sense of" look like `ARRAY(0x012345)`

Comment: As others have pointed out, what you have is correct. Alternatively, you can also use negative index positions to access array items relative to the _end_ of the array. For example: `print $some_array[-2];`

Answer (score 3):

It does print the second to last element in the array:

```
my @nums = qw(a b c d e);
print "$nums[$#nums-1]\n"; # prints 'd'
```

Here, `$#nums` gives the last index of an array (in this case 4 - arrays are zero-based), and hence `$#nums - 1` gives array element 3.

A more common way of writing this would be:

`$array[-2]`

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of `$some_array[$#some_array - 1]` depends on how many elements `@some_array` has.

If `@some_array` has 2 or more elements (`scalar @array >= 2`, or equivalently `$#array >= 1`), then your statement:

```
print $some_array[$#some_array - 1];
```

should work correctly. Say the array has 10 elements, then `$#some_array == 9`, and you'll print `$some_array[8]`, the second-to-last element.

If `@some_array` has just one element, then `$#some_array == 0`, and you'll print the "`-1`th" element. Negative array indices are treated specially: `-1` gives you the *last* element of the array, `-2` the second-to-last, and so forth. And if your goal is to print the second-to-last element of the array, you should be using this feature.

If `@some_array` is *empty* (`scalar @some_array == 0`, `$#some_array == -1`), then your statement will try to print `$some_array[-2]`, which doesn't exist, resulting in an error message.